# Curious as to why system said it was loading php.ini file from different directory

Tags: php, apache

I was wondering why my system says it is running the php from the **/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini**
directory when in fact it was running it from the **/etc/php5/cli/php.ini** .

When I did a phpinfo() on a file in the directory of the folder, I received this however the changes to the configuration file wasn't impacting the server until I searched the whole system for a php.ini file and found the php.ini file under the cli/ directory:

[image]

Hopefully you can see it. I wasn't sure exactly how to put in onto SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your environment when php runs in command line mode it uses `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.
When you access it from browser php is running from apache. So then `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` is used.

Answer (score 2):

it's intentional so you can easily have different configuration depending on your runtime environment.